# How do I use cmake to build external libraries as well as my own application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to build a cross platform OpenGL application, which means building and including multiple libraries (glfw, glbinding, glm, etc.) Because my application is cross platform, it makes sense to use cmake to generate all the build scripts and not have to muck about with them myself. I am attempting to target Windows and Linux specifically.

A main feature that I need is that the libraries I need are not installed on the host system. Furthermore, they cannot be installed (due to administrative reasons). What I need is to build these libraries and then build my application.

I am mostly working on Windows using Visual Studio 2017, which has cmake support included. Currently, I have attempted to build these libraries myself, however I am having many issues getting find_package to do the right thing.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
project/
|-src/
 |- my sources for my application
|-include/
 |- my header files
|-external/
 |-glfw-3.2.1/
 |-glbinding-2.1.4/
 |-glfw-build/
 |-glbinidng-build/
```

So I am attempting to build the external libraries and use them in my application. I am also attempting to follow cmake best practices. My CMakeLists.txt currently looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(glTestProj)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "external/")
find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(glbinding REQUIRED)

add_executable(glTest src/main.cpp)

target_compile_features(glTest PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_compile_options(glTest PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra)

target_link_libraries(
    glTest 
        glfw
        glbinding::glbinding
)
```

The libraries in question ([glfw](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package) and [glbinding](https://github.com/cginternals/glbinding#tips-for-linking)) both have instructions on including them via cmake, however I am running into this issue:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
  CMake did not find one.
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" (requested
  version 3.2) with any of the following names:
    glfw3Config.cmake
    glfw3-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Comment: Do these CMake modules already exist for these external dependencies? If not you might use instead find_library(...), which is a simpler process. If they do exist, what problems/errors are you having exactly? Packages normally define variables like ${glfw_LIBRARIES} -- this is the point of using the package feature rather than specifying dependent libraries directly e.g. "glfw"

Comment: @JamesBeilby Sorry I forgot to include the actual error, updating question.

Comment: If you're intending to build the packages yourself, then you probably shouldn't be using `find_package` which is meant for finding packages on the system, not for finding things you build as part of the project.  (If the libraries aren't set up to build using CMake, you might look into using the `ExternalProject` module to drive the builds of the libraries.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler That is really useful to know, thanks. These libraries do build with cmake, what would be the proper way to build them if necessary and link to them?

Comment: You can include the CMake files under the `external` directory in your own CMake project using the `include(...)` command. Then when you specify glfw etc. targets as dependencies of your own targets (using target_link_libraries), CMake will automatically build the dependent targets and locate them for you. You should not need `find_package` or `find_library` at all, if it is the case that they are all CMake-driven.

Comment: Just put `add_subdirectory(external)` first which in turn adds the subdirectories to build the libraries; and then link your executable against the targets built by these subdirectories.

Comment: (Of course, it might turn out in practice that the CMake files for the libraries assume they're top-level, and won't work as a subdirectory of a larger project.  Then you would have the choice of either fixing this assumption, or else using `ExternalProject` anyway so that the subdirectories are built as somewhat independent CMake builds.)